# inline css and html tags in react gives Error

Tags: reactjs

I created a page using Frontpage as my page Editor, Now I want to use this same HTML page in my React Js app. Now here is what I am facing.
I try to close the tags `</>` in this way but I appear to be having an error on `</table>` and `</tr>` and the inline CSS styling.
Although other codes seem to work fine there still are some things that are returning some Errors in Vs code.

Why is this so? Is there something I am missing?

```
import './InstaClone.css';
import React from 'react';


const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Hi from React JS');
}

const MainLogin = () =>{
    return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div align="center"/>
    <table border="0" width="61%"/>
        <tr/>
            <td width="370">
            <img border="0" src="images/43cc71bb1b43_2-removebg-preview.png" width="370" height="584"/></td>
            <td bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#C0C0C0">
            &nbsp;</td>
            <td bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#C0C0C0" width="415"/>
            <table border="0" width="100%" height="301" bordercolordark="#C0C0C0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" className="loginContainer"/>
                <tr>
                    <td bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#C0C0C0" border="1" height="74">
                    <p align="center"/>
                    <img border="0" src="images/images-removebg-preview.png" width="168" height="70"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr/>
                    <td height="46">

                    <p align="center"/>
                    <input type="text" name="T1" placeholder="  Phone number, username or email" size="33" className="inputBox"/></td>
                <tr/>
                <tr/>
                    <td height="49"/>
                    <p align="center"><input type="text" placeholder ="  Password" name="T2" size="33" className="inputBox"/></p>
                <tr/>
                <tr>
                    <td height="43"/>
                        <p align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="B1" className="buttonLogin"/></p>
                        <p/>

                    <td/>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="23">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <p align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2"/></p>
                    <a href="https://google.com">
                    Forgot Password?</a><font/></td>
                </tr>
            <table/>
            
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <table border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="48" className="donthaveAccount"/>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <p align="center"><font face="Arial" size="2"/>Don't Have an 
                    Account?
                    <a href="https://google.com">
                    Sign Up</a><font/></p></td>
                </tr>
            <table/>
            <p align="center"><font face="Arial">Get the app</font></p>
            <table border="0" width="100%"/>
                <tr/>
                    <td width="204"/>
                    <p align="center"/>
                    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="images/appstore.png" width="169" height="51" align="right"/>
                    <td/>
                    <p align="center"/>
                    <input type="image" src="images/googlePlay.png" width="169" height="50" align="left"/>
                <tr/>
            <table/>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p/>&nbsp;
        <tr/>
    <table/>
    <p/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>
    );
}

export default MainLogin;
```

And the error which I received:

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleSubmit')
MainLogin
D:/react/instagramc/src/MainLogin.js:12
   9 | 
  10 | const MainLogin = () =>{
  11 |     return (
> 12 |     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  13 |     <div align="center"/>
  14 |  <table border="0" width="61%"/>
  15 |      <tr/>
View compiled
▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.
Module.<anonymous>
D:/react/instagramc/src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1383:30
__webpack_require__
D:/react/instagramc/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
D:/react/instagramc/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1506:18
__webpack_require__
D:/react/instagramc/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
D:/react/instagramc/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
D:/react/instagramc/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:73
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code carefully. td is not a self closing element but there are some parts where you closed it like . Plus you are not supposed to you use styles in this way but by indexing them with the classes you used in your css.

For example:

```
<td className='my_td'></td>
```

then in your css

```
.my_td {width:24px;}
```

Comment: worked on those , now i am getting a very new error. Had to put them in classes then the errors disappeared,now its a new error i am getting 

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleSubmit')

Please see edits for source code

Comment: @Blaq Try do define the handleSubmit function in the MainLogin() and remove the this since you are not using a class component. It should fix your issue. To be precise, put the function definition before the return of the MainLogin and remove the this. before handleSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: the `handleSubmit` was not found. You forgot to define your `handleSubmit` inside of the `MainLogin` component.

To solve, put the `handleSubmit` function in the `MainLogin` component:

```
const MainLogin = () => {
    const handleSubmit = (event) =>{  // ----> moved to here
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Hi from React JS');
    }

    return ( // rest of the codes )
}
```

Finally, pass the `handleSubmit` function to the `onSubmit`:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
```

The `this` keyword is used in the class component definition and no more need in the **functional component** structure.